# Query all documents created by a particular user

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to return a list of documents created by a certain user, how do I? I'm using Firestore.

It's currently like this:

```
firestore.get({ collection: 'jobs' });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the user id you want to search by. If its the current user you could do something like...

```
const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
```

then you search for all the jobs collection documents where the userId field matches you userId above...

```
firebase.firestore()
      .collection('jobs')
      .where('userId', '==', userId)
      .get()
      .then(collection => {
        const docs = collection.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        console.log(docs)
      });
```

I console logged the docs, but you can return them or set a field in components state, or whatever else you want to do with them.

Comment: If I have an account authenticated by facebook or email the uids are different.

Comment: Can you explain please. A uid is a uid, each auth account gets one when the user is created. When a user connects a social account, they also have a provider uid. You can find that at `user.providerData[0].uid`. Regardless, you just need to search by whatever value you saved on the userId field in the first place.

Comment: the uids are different:

My uid in facebook provider: 898207047023983 and my uid in google provider: allancarlosdeveloper@gmail.com.

How I going search a user with same email but with different uids

Comment: Ok. What's the issue? I'm guessing you need to search by the auth uid, not the provider uid. Like I said above,  you need to search by whatever value you saved on the userId field in the first place. Please explain what the problem is and what you would like to happen.

Comment: I want that a user see yours "jobs" created, independent if he sign in with auth email or facebook.

Comment: Store the users firebase auth uid in the userId field job documents and then you can query by uid as outlined in my response.

Comment: The user's uid logged in by Facebook or google are the same, but the uid of the user logged in by email is different.

Comment: Sure, these will always be different, you want teh user uid, not the provider uid. The user uid is created when you create the user in firebase auth. Adding providers to that user is seperate.

Comment: So how do you associate a user with a certain "job" created, regardless if he's going to come in with email, facebook, or google?

Comment: When you create a user in firebase auth, they are issued with a unique ID. How you create the user, email or social or anonymously, is irrelevant. That uid will always correspond to that user. If you then want to attach additional social profiles to that user you can (like so https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) but it won't change their original uid. When you create a document, add the uid as a field on the doc and then you can always query for it in the manner I outlined in my response.